# How to bind an binary array to a flutter shader

Tags: flutter, shader, tiff

I have a tif file of which i want to load one channel to a flutter shader.
Each pixel of the tif is defined with 4 bits. Using a sampler2D will scramble multiple of those 4bits together and create a floating point value out of it, making it impossible to descramble the exact values of every pixel on the shader side.

Using a vec2/3/4 doesn´t help since i need to transfer a whole image at once.

How can i transfer a array of bits of arbitrary size from flutter to the shader without losing informaiton?

I am using the "flutter_shader 0.1.2" (https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_shaders) with version 460 core. In that package its only allowed to use standard vector stuff. But most important, only the sampler2D is available. What i need is a sampler that doesn´t convert everything into a floating point value. For example a isampler1d, isampler2d or something like that.

Converting every 4 bit into an floating point and move that float array to the shader isn´t an option since execution time is critical and calculating the float values would take to much time.